# F# linq expression error with { and return can't be used within the function

Tags: c#, linq, f#, return

I can't seem to get the following functions in F# to work. I've attached the code below.

**First issue:** On the line where it has

```
Select(g => new {Cluster
```

the error displayed is 'unexpected symbol '{' in expression'.

**Second issue:** On the line where it does a conditional check

```
If (EmptyCluster(_normalisedDataToCluster) = true) then return false
```

complains with the error, 'This construct may only be used within computation expressions. To return a value from an ordinary function simply write the expression without return'.

```
let EmptyCluster(data : List<DataPointClass>) =
    let emptyCluster = data.GroupBy(s => s.Cluster)
                           .OrderBy(s => s.Key)
                           .Select(g => new {Cluster = g.Key, Count = g.Count}) 
    //complains about the curly braces inside the Select expression above

    for item in emptyCluster do
        if (item.Count = 0) then
            return true

    return false

let UpdateDataPointMeans() =
    if (EmptyCluster(_normalisedDataToCluster) = true) then
        return false //complains about this return statement

    let mutable groupToComputeMeans = _normalisedDataToCluster
        .GroupBy(s => s.Cluster).OrderBy(s => s.Key)

    let mutable clusterIndex = 0
    let mutable height = 0.0
    let mutable weight = 0.0

    for item in groupToComputeMeans do
        for value in item do
            height <- height + value.Height
            weight <- weight + value.Weight

        _clusters.[clusterIndex].Height <- height / Convert.ToDouble item.Count
        _clusters.[clusterIndex].Weight <- weight / Convert.ToDouble item.Count

        clusterIndex <- clusterIndex + 1
        height <- 0.0
        weight <- 0.0

    true

type DataPointClass(height : double, weight : double) = class
    let mutable _height = height
    let mutable _weight = weight
    let mutable cluster = 0

    member self.Height with get () = _height and set (value) = _height  <- value

    member self.Weight with get () = _weight and set (value) = _weight  <- value

    member self.Cluster with get () = cluster and set (value) = cluster <- value

    new() = 
        DataPointClass(-1.0, -1.0)
        then
            printfn "Error initialising"

end
```

Comment: It appears that you want us to load this code up in Visual Studio and troubleshoot it for you.  Isn't that a lot to ask of some random strangers on the Internet?  You didn't even tell us what the error message is, or on what line of code you're getting it.  If you're having trouble posting pictures; that's a spam-prevention feature.  Post a link to the picture, and a high-rep user will edit it into your question.

Comment: Also, the title of your question could be a lot better.  It says nothing about the nature of your problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey updated the post.

Comment: This looks like C# in F# clothing.  You need to learn how to write this stuff so that it's idiomatic in F#.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374.aspx

Comment: Please learn some F# syntax first...

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the link but this is a shorter expression so why do the full query expression when you don't have to?

Comment: @Mikhail that's what I'm trying to do however, if there's a more succinct syntax which is allowed then I don't see why I shouldn't use it.

Comment: Learn how to follow the rules first.  Then you can learn how to break them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're not really writing F# code and you really should learn how to write things that way. It doesn't seem to make much sense to use Linq for example... You should also consider making it so that your code sample is actually something that can compile so we don't have to guess for example what type is `DataPointClass`.

That said to address your specific questions:

***First issue***: 
If you look at the [constructor documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233192.aspx), you see that the keyword `new` is used if you have a custom type. Something like this:

```
type MyClass(clus, ct) = 
    let mutable cluster = clus
    let mutable count = ct
    member this.Cluster with get() = cluster
    member this.Count with get() = count
    new() = MyClass("", 0)

let test = new MyClass()
```

However, it seems you are using a record type here, which means you don't need the new keyword at all... Something like `{Cluster = g.Key; Count = g.Count}` will automatically create a new class of the appropriate `MyClass`.

***Second issue***: 
Looking at the [keyword guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233249.aspx) again, we see that the keyword `return` is only used in *async* workflows: `Used to indicate a value to provide as the result of a computation expression.` It isn't used to indicate the return value of a function. To return from a function you don't need to use any keyword at all. Here's a simple example:

```
let multiplyByTwo x = x*2
```

Notice how we don't have to use return at all. The compiler knows automatically.